# Resume sentence fragment conundrum

Tags: grammar, resume

I am updating my resume and need help making this sentence grammatically correct.  Is it ok as is?  It is for a bullet point list of job duties on a resume.

“Review, prioritize and respond to executive's correspondence; determine when executive action is required.”

Answer (score 1):

I have found only one point: the punctuation. You end the bullet point with a full stop although it is not a complete sentence. You can do that if this is the last list item and all previous items end with a comma, like this:

- first item,
- second item,
- last item.

Alternatively omit all punctuation:

- first item
- second item
- last item

Or if you rephrase everything to form complete sentences use a full stop each time, but I do not recommend it in this case.

There are also other styles of punctuation; there seems to be no real consensus. You find various questions and answers on English Language SE. The important thing is be consistent. If you have other bullet lists in your resume, apply the same style.